# mysql SUM returns NULL when using NOT

Tags: mysql

Can someone please help me understand why this works and I get the correct SUM value:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(factura_ron) AS total_ron, 
    SUM(factura_eur) AS total_eur, 
    SUM(factura_usd) AS total_usd 
FROM facturi 
WHERE (status_id = 2 OR status_id = 4 OR status_id = 6) AND (factura_type_id IS NULL OR factura_type_id = 1 OR factura_type_id = 2 OR factura_type_id = 4)
```

But this does not work as intended and all I get is NULL, when using the NOT:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(factura_ron) AS total_ron, 
    SUM(factura_eur) AS total_eur, 
    SUM(factura_usd) AS total_usd 
FROM facturi 
WHERE (status_id = 2 OR status_id = 4 OR status_id = 6) AND NOT (factura_type_id = 3 OR factura_type_id = 5)
```

I also have tried

```
status_id IN (2, 4, 6) AND factura_type_id NOT IN (3, 5)
```

or

```
factura_type_id <> 3 AND factura_type_id <> 5
```

The SUMs are made as following:

STATUS:

Status null - sent

Status 2 - paid

Status 4 - prepaid

Status 6 - paid in tranches

TYPE:

Factura type null - Standard

Factura Type 1 - Storage

Factura Type 2 - Maintenance

Factura Type 3 - Deposit

Factura Type 4 - Storno

Factura Type 5 - Storno Deposit

The sum is just made for one column:

```
ID factura_usd factura_type status_id
1.     20          5           null
2.     10          5           2
3.    -10          3           2
4.    100          5           2
5.   -100          3           null
6.   2000          5           2
7.   2300          null        null
8.    550          null        2
```

The sum for factura_usd (I will omit the other 2 eur and ron column for simplicity) should be 550 USD with the first version of the code, but with the second version where I try to omit Type 3 (Deposit) and 5 (Storno Deposit) I get NULL. Both codes should have exactly the same result, but in the first version I have to include all the types except 3 and 5 (which is impractical).

Nothing works when I am trying to avoid the said 2 values. What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: Pretty hard to answer this without sample data that demonstrates the issue. You should read [How to ask a good SQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: Show us the current output of both query and try to run the query without `SUM()` and see the result.

Comment: I have added the example information for clarity.

Comment: The curious thing is that if I write: WHERE (status_id = '2' OR status_id = '4' OR status_id = '6') AND (factura_type_id = '3' OR factura_type_id = '5') I get 2100 USD, but if I just add NOT: WHERE (status_id = '2' OR status_id = '4' OR status_id = '6') AND NOT (factura_type_id = '3' OR factura_type_id = '5') then I simply get NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that NOT IN can't figure out that NULL is something to take into account when outside the specified values.

The solution is this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(factura_ron) AS total_ron, 
    SUM(factura_eur) AS total_eur, 
    SUM(factura_usd) AS total_usd 
FROM facturi 
WHERE status_id IS (2,4,6) AND (factura_type_id NOT IN (3,5) OR factura_type_id IS NULL)
```